# Problems with Serial Port in visual basic

Tags: vb.net

I've got a problem. Whenever I use a command to open serial port, if I use Baud Rate from 19200 and above, VB will automatically send some data (I don't know what this data is and where it's from) to controller via Serial Port. But when I use Baud Rate 9600 this problem doesn't occur.

```
    '-----------------------------vb code----------------------------------

    Imports System
    Imports System.Threading
    Imports System.IO.Ports
    Imports System.ComponentModel


    Public Class Form1

        Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)   
Handles MyBase.Load
            With SerialPort1

                .PortName = "Com6"
                .RtsEnable = True
                .DataBits = 8
                .BaudRate = 19200
                .Parity = IO.Ports.Parity.None
                .StopBits = StopBits.One
                .Open()


            End With
        End Sub

        Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

            Dim int As Integer = 7

            SerialPort1.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(int), 0, 1)


        End Sub
    End Class

    '------------------------end of vb code---------------------------

    //------------------- START OF ARDUINO SKETCH -------------------

    void setup(){

    Serial.begin(19200);
    Serial1.begin(19200 );

    }


    void loop(){
       if (Serial.available()) {
             int val = Serial.read();
             Serial1.print(val);
          }  
    }

    //------------- END OF ARDUINO SKETCH ----------------
```

The result

```
2552552552557
```

I don't know what this data padded to the value I want to send is and where it's from: `255255255255`

Whereas `7` is the data that I want to send.

Comment: Is it possible you have a little endian/big endian mismatch?

This post in vbforums may help you: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?611217-RESOLVED-Reading-Bytes-(Little-Endian-Big-Endian)

Comment: Are you just trying to find out where the data is coming form, or you want to know how to change the data you are sending? It sounds like this data may be in hex form or ASCII.

Comment: Getting 255 in Arduino is not a complete mystery, you'll get it when you interpret the value -1 as a byte.  Which is returned by Serial.read() when you call it when there is no byte available.  That explanation doesn't otherwise jive with your code snippet.  Electrical noise problems get worse at higher baudrates, that's always a random number generator.